# backbone.js template is not rendering data even though model passing data

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone.js template is not rendering data even though model passing data

**View**

```
var SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function() {
            this.render();
        },
        model: Section,
        className: 'div-body-row',
        template: _.template($("#table-body-template").html()),
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
```

**Template:-**

```
<script type="text/templete" id="table-body-template">
    <div class="inner-div col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><%= id %></div>
    <div class="inner-div col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><%= roomNumber %></div>
    <div class="inner-div col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><%= dateTime %></div>
    <div class="inner-div col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><%= personId %></div>
    <div class="inner-div col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><%= courseId %></div>
    <div class="inner-div col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><%= termId %></div>
</script>
```

this is entire code

```
var Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        id : '',
        roomNumber : '',
        dateTime : '',
        person : '',
        course : '',
        term : ''
    }
});

var SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.render();
    },
    model: Section,
    className: 'div-body-row',
    template: _.template($('#table-body-template').html()),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        var a = this.model.get("id");
        var b = this.model.get("sectionName");
        var c = this.model.get("roomNumber");
        var d = this.model.get("dateTime");
        var e = this.model.get("person");
        var f = this.model.get("course");
        var g = this.model.get("term");
        console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
        return this;
    }
});

var SectionCollection  = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Section,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/student-faculty-attendance/section/sectionDetails'+'?id='+id,
});

var SectionCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.render();
    },
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'div-body',
    singleSectionview: function(section){
        var sectionView = new SectionView({model: section});
            this.$el.append(sectionView.el);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.singleSectionview, this);
        return this;
    }
});

var section_collection = new SectionCollection();
var section_collection_view;
section_collection.fetch({
success: function(collection) {
    console.log(collection);
    if (collection.length) {
        section_collection_view = new SectionCollectionView({collection: collection});
        $("#table-body").append(section_collection_view.el);
    } else {
       console.log("Collection is empty!!");
    }
}
```

And even template is generating but without data

```
<div id="table-body" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="div-body">
    <div class="div-body-row">
       <div class="inner-div"></div>
       <div class="inner-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-body-row">
      <div class="inner-div"></div>
      <div class="inner-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-body-row">
      <div class="inner-div"></div>
      <div class="inner-div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are the logs printing values?

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `model: Section` in the view constructor, where `Section` is probably a model constructor. This is usually done in a collection, and the collection later constructs model instances using the specified constructor. View does not do that.

Calling `toJSON()` directly on a model constructor will result in error

```
Uncaught TypeError: .toJSON is not a function
```

because `toJSON` is defined on the prototype of constructor to be shared with it's instances, not directly on the constructor.

You should do:

```
var SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new Section()
});
```

but in this case if there are multiple instances of this view, they will share same model, which is generally not desired. Ideally you should create a model instance per view instance, like:

```
var view = new SectionView({model: new Section() });
```

or

```
var SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.model = new Section();
        this.render();
    },
```

Comment: Hi @T J, thanks for your time. I tried with your suggestion, but still its the same issue. any other suggestions are welcome!! thanks again.

Comment: @RajanikanthDesai This is the issue in the code shown in question. There can be lot of other issues in your code (Entire code for rendering a view is not in question, it only has a constructor). I suggest creating an [mcve] pr posting the remaining code

Comment: i have uploaded entire code. Plz have a look at it. If you find something wrong suggest me i will try that. Thanks!!

Comment: @RajanikanthDesai the code you posted still has the problem mentioned above... Please post the code with the fix so that it is easy to figure out what is the issue according to the fixed code.